# Read a list of dictionaries with a list of dictionaries contained within, Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file that contains a list of dictionaries that each contain another list of dictionaries. As an example say the list is customers and the list within the customer dictionary is a shopping cart like this:

```
[{"id":11,"name":"Jane Doe","cart":[{"name":"milk","cost":3},{"name":"apple","cost":2}]},{"id":04,"name":"John Smith","cart":[{"name":"cake","cost":4},{"name":"chips","cost":1}]}]
```

What is the best way to read this in and parse out the data?

Comment: *a .txt file that contains a list of dictionaries* - is it json string?

Comment: I would have answered ``ast.literal_eval`` or ``json.loads`` but the string you posted is syntactically incorrect for both json data and python literal strings. What produced it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a JSON file. Use the `json` module